# pip install ibm-db seems failed. keep "Getting requirements to build wheel" for minutes

Tags: python, pip, db2

my pip info

```
pip3 --version
pip 22.0.3 from /myPath/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

while i install "ibm-db" for the lastest version, it shows

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting ibm-db
  Using cached ibm_db-3.1.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... -
```

and nothing happened anymore.
what shoule I do?
thanks

Comment: Which OS? The pip install downloads a set of files with the CLI driver and builds the actual Python driver.

Comment: Yes, it has having issue with it. i was getting lot of requirement issue.  But using ```pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip``` . Helped me to install on My Machine which is linux.

Obviously you will need to install required packages.
Please upload full error

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have gcc and python-devel installed. If not (Assuming a Redhat derivative, something similar for others)

```
sudo dnf install gcc
sudo dnf install python3-devel
```

The pip installation seems to access some system files, despite being installed with --user, so you may have to:

```
sudo pip3 install --user ibm_db
```

You can find more info at: [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db/)